# Unable to start Payara (payara6) server instance in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, java-11, payara, payara-micro

Whenever I try to run instance of payara server in vscode. Not able to start the server. Following is the error I'm facing in the output window of vs code.

> Error: Could not find or load main class Files\payara6\glassfish.lib.grizzly-npn-api.jar
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Files\payara6\glassfish.lib.grizzly-npn-api.jar

- JDK version 11
- Windows 10 pro
- payara version 6.2023.11

Expecting to run a server after clicking run but ended up getting error

Answer (score 1):

This means that Payara can't work properly when it's installed in a location that contains spaces in the path. You probably installed it into the "C:\Program Files" directory.

Move the Payara installation to a directory, which doesn't contain spaces. For example into "C:\payara".

You can also try [GlassFish 7](https://glassfish.org/), which is very similar to Payara 6, but doesn't use the grizzly npn library and may not suffer from this issue.